# sqlite finding patterns of values in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, rows

I am an SQL beginer, so may be my question as no sense.

I leaned up my need to to following example.

I have a table T with a column C of type integer
I have 'random' values in this C column like, and I give here an index column

```
Nx C
 1 1
 2 5
 3 3
 4 7
 5 5
 6 8
 7 3
 8 5
 9 2
10 7
11 3
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to select the row that have C==5 if 2 row down we have C==7

Here I have a match at row 2 and row 8

Is there a way to achieve this, I though may be with an 
internal 'index' (or rowid) and 'may be' joining the same table.

Thanx in advance for any clues.
Cheers,
Phi

Comment: Table eaten reformating my question

Answer (score 1):

If by "two rows down" you mean the row whose `Nx` value is exactly two larger, then you can do this with a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tplus2
     on t.nx = tplus2.nx - 2 and
        t.c = 5 and
        tplus2.c = 7;
```

Comment: Thanx Gordon, look interesting, should I explicitly create the NX column, or is there a 'kind of' internal one that I could use?

Comment: @Phi . . . There *is* a row id column in SQLite, but I would recommend that you explicitly create the column yourself.  The row id may not always behave the way that you want it to.

Comment: I start to understand the diff between 'comment' and 'answer' in stackoverflow :). Ok I will create and autoinc ndx col. The row once entered in the table are never deleted, then rowid may be good too...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want the actual row with 5 in it returned and this is what I had come up with:

```
Select *
from tbl
Where C = 5 and Nx = 
(Select Nx
from tbl
where C = 7) - 2
```